# как инвертировать елементы односвязного списка?

Tags: c++, список

Подскажите, как реализовать функцию, что бы  инвертировать елементы односвязного списка?

```
struct Data
{   int a;
};

struct List
{   Data d;
List *next;
};
```

Comment: Инвертировать - это что сделать? Обратить порядок?

Comment: @Harry да, поставить элементы в обратном порядке:)